# Converting variable reference to value?

Tags: c++, debugging

I am using `list` from `STL`. To access I used `l.front()` or `l.back()`. Both of these methods return reference. I am copying content of one list into other so don't want reference. As the methods are returning references so I want to know that is there some other way by which I can convert reference to value? And I will just receive value not reference.

```
int main()
{

    list<int> l;
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(5);
    l.push_back(7);
    l.push_back(9);

    while( ! l.empty() )
    {
        cout<<l.front()<<endl;
        l.pop_front();
    }

    list<int> l1;
    l1.push_back(10);
    l1.push_back(15);
    l1.push_back(30);


    l.push_back( l1.front() );   // here I need value not reference.


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run or debug this to see the results?

Comment: You receive a reference, but the `push_back` function takes that exactly, so there's no problem.

Comment: yes. list `l` now has only 10.

Comment: @faranwath but push_back() also removes all previously pushed integers. Why is that so?

Comment: @user3461957 Didn't you `pop_front`ed them just before?

Comment: OOPs ................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will indeed get value

```
l.push_back( l1.front() );   // here I need value not reference
```

because the value referenced to by `l1.front()` will be used to create an element of list `l`.
There is no any need to create any intermediate temporary object that only to get the target value.:)

try this simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    std::list<int> l;

    std::list<int> l1;

    l1.push_back( 10 );
    l1.push_back( 15 );
    l1.push_back( 30 );

    l.push_back( l1.front() );

    for ( int x : l1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

As you will see each list contains its own element with value 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [std::list::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back). There are two versions taking different input arguments:

1. `const T& value`: the new element is initialized as a copy of value.
2. `T&& value`: value is moved into the new element

In your case, `l1.front()` is an lvalue reference `T&`, so version 1 is chosen and the value is copied, which is what you want.